# Accessing constants outside a class

Tags: ruby, oop

When I want to access the constant `CONST` in class `Test` in

```
class Test
  CONST = 7
end
```

from outside of the class, I have to do this:

```
puts Test::CONST
```

Why do I get an error when I do this?

```
puts obj::CONST
```

If `obj` is an object of the `Test` class, why do I get an error if I try to access the constant through the object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because an instance object and a class object are not the same thing.  The namespace exists on the class object, and does not exist on the instance.

You can, however, ask the instance for it's class, then drill into that.

```
puts obj.class::CONST
```

Comment: Thank you, simple and straight to the point **Because an instance object and a class object are not the same thing**